# how to develop a lambda on SAM but deploy without api gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam

I am using SAM to develop a lambda that is triggered by SNS.
When I am using SAM, it seems I get API GATEWAY associated to the Lambda when I deploy.
It is nice in dev, but not in prod.
How would I develop a Lambda without deploying it attached to an API GATEWAY?

Comment: Any reason why you are using SAM to develop your Lambda function vs coding it using the Lambda runtime API and an AWS SDK such as Java, JavaScript or Python?

Comment: @smac2020 was not aware of Lambda runtime API  -> checking that. Are there similar tools to emulate locally Dynmo and SNS?

Comment: See my response below.

Answer (score 1):

For future readers: This is [now](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/announcing-aws-lambda-function-urls-built-in-https-endpoints-for-single-function-microservices/) (Apr/2022) possible using Lambda Function [URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/urls-tutorial.html#lambda-url-tutorial-sam). An example SAM config will be  as below. Please note that you will have to invoke lambda using `sam local invoke`. You cannot use `sam local start-api` as there is no api gateway

```yaml
HelloWorldFunction:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    CodeUri: hello-world/
    Handler: app.lambdaHandler
    Runtime: nodejs18.x
    FunctionUrlConfig:
      AuthType: NONE
```

Answer (score 0):

***"I was not aware of Lambda runtime API"***

Using the Lambda runtime API and the AWS SDKs, as a developer, you can build more flexible Lambda functions with the exact functionality that you want.

For example, you can build Lambda functions that can invoke multiple AWS Services to perform a given use case. For example, from a Lambda function,  I want to detect PPE information in images within an Amazon S3 bucket, store the results in an Amazon DynamoDB table, and use the SES service to email the results.

Here are a few end to end tutorials.

For example - here are two JavaScript examples:

[Creating and using Lambda functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/lambda-create-table-example.html)

[Creating scheduled events to execute AWS Lambda functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/scheduled-events-invoking-lambda-example.html)

Here are some Java runtime examples:

[Creating an AWS Lambda function that detects images with Personal Protective Equipment](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_lambda_ppe)

[Creating an Amazon Web Services Lambda function that tags digital assets located in Amazon S3 buckets](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_lambda_tag_assets)

[Creating an ETL workflow by using AWS Step Functions and the AWS SDK for](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/Creating_etl_workflow) Java

**UPDATE**

Once you test your code in an IDE, deploy it and test it from the Lambda console. Once it is successfully invoked, you will see a message like this:

[image]

Comment: For my understanding, This require to deploy to AWS to be tested, I can not test it locally. Is this correct?

Comment: You can test the code locally. For example, if you are using an IDE, you can set a break points and step through the code. Then once you are happy with the code, deploy it to AWS and Test it from the Lambda Console. You will see a success message when the Lambda function is successful

Answer (score 0):

Another option I found, this time within SAM is define the function with a different Event source.
The Lambda will be exposed if it's event source is defined as **Api**
You can define it as many other things (S3,Sns,Sqs etc)

Here is an example of a function triggered by and http event via api gateway, and the other one, by Sns. The config for SNS is not complete, Check this link for full details https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md

in `template.yaml` Notice the **Events** section of each Lambda definition.

```
Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: hello-world/
      Handler: app.lambdaHandler
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /hello
            Method: get
  BooBooFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: booboo/
      Handler: app.lambdaHandler
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Events:
        BooBoo:
          Type: Sns # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
```